# Integer being wrongly parsed to String

Tags: javascript, parsing, integer, chess

I'm making a chess application for practice and something is throwing me off. My squares are numbered 1-64, with the first row holding 1 to 8, the next holding 9 to 16, and so on. Every time a player tries to move a piece my program checks if the destination square is a legal one according to the rules.

For my king I have a line like this:

```
else if (startID >= 58 && startID <= 63){ // bottom row
                if (endID == startID - 7 || endID == startID - 8 || endID == startID - 9 || endID == startID - 1 || endID == startID + 1) return true;
            }
```

Basically if the king is on the last row (and not a corner square), check if the destination square is an adjacent square. However, all of them work except for this part which checks if the destination square is directly on the right:

```
endID == startID + 1
```

I've had other parts of the program struggle with using compare statements until I add a 'parseInt()' in front of the problematic variable. Is there a way to make sure a variable is always an integer?

Comment: Yes, use `parseInt(startID,10)`

Comment: No, JavaScript doesn't use types. But, why don't you use a nested array for maintaining the positions?

Comment: Where/how are you originally getting these values for `startID` and `endID`? From a HTML attribute?

Comment: Yes, they are both ID's of each individual square

Comment: The values of HTML attributes are always strings, you've to convert them to numbers when reading.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
var myStringNum = "1";
if (myStringNum === parseInt(myStringNum, 10) && myStringNum !== NaN){
    console.log('ok'); // does not print anything
}

var myNormalNum = 1;
if (myNormalNum === parseInt(myNormalNum, 10) && myNormalNum !== NaN){
    console.log('ok'); // prints ok
}
```

The trick is using the '===' operator.

Here is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1t26odke/).

Comment: When I replace all instances of == with === my program seems to not work anymore, maybe because I have parseInt() involved in some of the comparisons

Comment: @user3509099 Before making any comparisons make sure you convert the variable you use, to an integer using method parseInt(myVar, 10);.